# ViewPager show empty screen initially but displays data on swiping back

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-tabs

Android ViewPager shows empty screen initially but displays data on swiping back.
Scenario:
I am using 3 tabs with recyclerview. I am using volley library to get server data. On loading the app all tabs are empty but on swiping to the 3rd tab and back to the first the data displays on the 1st and 3rd tab. The Second tab remains empty.

Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: You are using emulator or device?

Comment: By default, `ViewPager` will keep one offscreen page in memory at a time. This means that when you swipe to the third tab, the first tab is destroyed. When you then swipe back to the first tab, it will be recreated. It sounds to me like some data is not available when the pages are first rendered, so they display as empty. When your page is destroyed and then recreated, the data is available and things are displayed just fine. Without your source code, though, I can't say anything more than that.

Comment: @BenP. Hey can you help me with the following

https://stackoverflow.com/q/47030663/7149567